# Exercise from Geometry of algebraic curves by Arbarello, Cornalba, Griffiths, Harris

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let π:C′→C an unramified double cover of a complex Riemann surface C of genus g. With the symbol Nmπ we mean the norm application that takes a meromorphic function on C′ named h and produce a meromorphic function on C named Nmπ(h) defined as
Nmπ(h)(p)=∏q∈π−1(p)h(q)ν(q)

where ν(q) is the multiplicity of q in the fiber of p respect to π. Write (f)=(Nmπ(h)) the principal divisor associated to the function Nmπ(h).

I would like to prove that:
1) if τ:C′→C′ is the sheet interchange involution for the double cover π. Show that there exist a function s meromorphic on C′ such that
s(q)=−s(τ(q))
2)Let τ as in the point 1) and let f a meromorphic function on C′ such that f=−f∘τ. Show that (Nmπ(f)) is divisible by 2 i.e. we can write (Nmπ(f))=2D.

Comment: I'm afraid MO is not the right place to ask about exercises on standard textbooks.

Comment: how does this work?  can we just transfer the question to MathSE or do we have to wait for the OP to do so?

Comment: The question was already posted here and has an answer. See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1113549/12885).